# js. Как отследить ajax-логи?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем привет!

Такая ситуация, нужно при нажатии на определенную кнопку на сайте отследить ajax-запросы, проблема в том что при нажатии происходит редирект на другую страницу и содержимое истории network очищается, что делать?

Можно ли как-то запретить любую переадресацию на сайте с помощью js или чего-то другого?

Comment: В настройках инструментов разработчика должна быть галочка, отключающая очистку (в фаерфоксе называется «Включить непрерывные логи»)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо отметить флажок Preserve log.

[image: Preserve log]